# Issues with editCellTemplate in Devexterme datagrid

Tags: jquery, devextreme

I have a column in Devexterme datagrid(built using jquery) which has autocomplete editor inside a editCellTemplate.The editor  looses focus on subsequent edits to the same column and its no longer available for editing.
Below is the code snippet:

```
{
          dataField: 'fullTitle',
          caption: "Title",
          id:"IdFullTitle",
          dataType: "string",
          width: 150,
          setCellValue: function (newData, value, currentRowData) {
              this.defaultSetCellValue(newData, value); // default implementation.
          },
          editCellTemplate: function (cellElement, cellInfo) {
              $("#fullData").dxAutocomplete({
                  value: cellInfo.value,
                  valueChangeEvent: 'focusout',
                  dataSource: new DevExpress.data.CustomStore({
                      load: loadOptions => {
                          var filter;
                          var searchString = loadOptions.searchValue ? loadOptions.searchValue.toString() : '';

                          if (searchString.length >= 3) {
                          return $.ajax({
                              url: myurl,
                              type: 'POST',
                              contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
                              data: {
                                  name: searchString,
                              },
                              dataType: "json",
                          });

                          } else {


                          }

                      },
                  }),
                  valueExpr: "fullTitle",
                  searchExpr: "fullTitle",
                  searchEnabled: true,
                  onSelectionChanged: function (e) {
                      if (e.selectedItem && typeof(e.selectedItem) === "object") {

                      }
                  },
                  onValueChanged: args => {
                  }

              }).appendTo(cellElement);
          },
          validationRules: [{ type: "required" }],
          showEditorAlways: false,
          allowFiltering: true,
          allowEditing: true,
          fixed: true,
          fixedPosition: "left",
          allowReordering: false,

      }
```

TIA.